# configuration file of php

Tags: php

i'm trying to put my local database on a freewebhost but i keep having problems..

I've recently developed my website and im trying to put it to a free webhost. I have downloaded my sql database in the .gz, created a new database on my new webhost and imported it in. my page is still blanke, and the techsupport are telling me that i need to change my configuration file of my php script, to upload the new user name , database name etc.. but where is that config file? where i need to go to access it and replace my new users? is there any other step that i need to do?

Comment: Magento and free web hosting are mutually exclusive. Free web hosting will be a shared environment where strict controls are set up for fairness of sharing those resources. Magento will typically fall flat on its face when it runs out of resources.

Answer (score 2):

The file you're looking for in Magento is located in app/etc/local.xml. You can edit your database name, server, username, and password there.